# Какой размер ячейки памяти(минимального адресуемого объекта) у hdd?

Tags: железо

Какой размер ячейки памяти(минимального адресуемого объекта) у hdd?

Comment: 512 байт вроде как

Comment: Так много не может быть. int будет 512 байт занимать?

Comment: @Shilko2013 Есть смутное ощущение, что Вы предполагаете наличие какой-то логической связи между двумя вопросами: "Какой размер минимального адресуемого объекта у HDD?" и "int будет 512 байт занимать?" Поясните, в чем заключается эта связь?

Comment: @Shilko2013 Это ещё мало (см. мой ответ). И с чего Вы взяли, что `int` будет занимать 512 байт? Он будет занимать отведённый ему объём внутри этих 512 байт, соседствуя с другими данными. Кстати, Вы знаете, что при считывании данных из RAM, к примеру, в кэш процессора, считывание тоже идёт не побайтово, а блоками.

Answer (score 2):

Жёсткий диск (HDD) в настоящее время разбивается на сектора размером 512 байт. Сектор является минимально адресуемой единицей данных на диске. Существуют более современные диски, поддерживающие так называемый Advanced Format, согласно которому сектор занимает 4096 байт. Но для них предусмотрен режим эмуляции с размером сектора 512 байт.

Comment: Тут было бы уместно добавить ещё пару слов про файловые системы, и про размер кластера. :)